# syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...| u.permit( roles: [], :email,:password, :password_confirma... ... ^

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using `gem 'devise'` in my project. what is the difference between these two lines of code :

```
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)  { |u| u.permit( :email, :password, :password_confirmation, roles: [] ) }
```

and

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)  { |u| u.permit(roles: [], :email, :password, :password_confirmation ) }
```

Because when I tried second one I am getting this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...| u.permit( roles: [], :email,:password, :password_confirma... ... ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby has special syntax sugar for an argument, which is a hash. You must pass it last.

This

```
u.permit( :email, :password, :password_confirmation, roles: [] )
```

essentially means this

```
u.permit( :email, :password, :password_confirmation, { roles: [] } )
```

In the second example, you're trying to pass it as a first argument, which confuses ruby parser. Use the first form.

Comment: Good to know. I thought both the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby does some clever parsing to allow you to avoid excessive use of brackets and parentheses when the shape of data structures can be inferred by context. In the first case, `roles: []` is at the end of the string of parameters. It is inferred that it is a hash with a single key, `:roles` - equivalent to: `{ roles: [] }`

In the second case, the context is ambiguous - the key :roles could be pointing to an array composed of an empty array and some symbols: `{ roles: [ [], :email... ] }`, or it could just point to the empty array: `{ roles: [] }, :email, ...`

So, such a construction is not allowed, hence the syntax error

Answer (score -2):

You can't just switch out arguments for a function.
The difference is that the function expects something 'here' but you are passing it 'there'. And it's looking for something else 'there'.

Comment: This is basically correct. Now it only needs to be worded properly :)